# Conversion from strange template type

Tags: c++, templates, types

I have a number of vectors (the maths type) implemented as structs. There is a base `Vector`, which is a template, and then multiple implementations of the this template for vectors of different dimensions:

```
template<unsigned int D>
struct Vector
{
    float values[D];

    inline Vector<D> operator*(const Vector<D>& v) const
    {
        Vector<D> result;

        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < D; i++)
            result[i] = values[i] * v[i];

        return result;
    }

    float operator[](unsigned int i) const
    {
        return values[i];
    }
};
```

I have just included a single operator, but there are obviously others and various methods for taking the dot product etc. I then have implementations like so:

```
struct Vector2 : Vector<2>
{
    Vector2(float x = 0, float y = 0) : Vector<2>()
    { }
};
```

I then have two `Vector2`s that I attempt to use the multiplication operator on like: `Vector2 textureOffsetPixels = textureOffset * textureSampleSize;`

And it throws the error: `conversion from Vector<2u> to non-scalar type 'Vector2' requested`. What is up with the `Vector<2u>` and why does this not work? Both variables are of explicit type `Vector2`.

Comment: Hint: `Vector2 textureOffsetPixels = textureOffset;` will give the same error.

Comment: I thought structs defaulted to public inheritance @AmiTavory?

Comment: @Oktalist so, would that mean it's not a problem with the operator overload? Or just that the `operator=` suffers from a similar problem?

Comment: There is no implicit conversion from base class to derived class.

Comment: Oh, okay - so, how can I fix that? Would a `Vector2(const Vector<2>& v)` added constructor work?

Comment: Unrelated, but why does your `operator[]()` not return a reference? Also, the parameter should probably be of type `size_t` as well.

Comment: Thanks, what's better about a `size_t`? And there are two - that one and one that isn't `const` and returns a reference. So you can still use the `[]` operator on a `const Vector&`. I just didn't show both for conciseness.

Comment: [std::size_t](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t): *"**std::size_t** can store the maximum size of a theoretically possible object of any type (including array). [...] **std::size_t** is commonly used for array indexing and loop counting."* As for your indexing operator: You could return a const ref (`const float&`). This is more useful, when a container stores compound objects, to avoid copying objects.

Comment: Oh, okay, I'll do that then - thanks! And ah, hadn't thought of that, I'll change it but I suspect it wouldn't be too much of a worry for a single float.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to be able to convert the result of `textureOffset * textureSampleSize`, which is a `Vector<2>`, into a `Vector2`, you need a conversion function. A constructor like this will suffice:

```
Vector2(const Vector<2> &base) : Vector<2>(base) {}
```

The error mentions `Vector<2u>` because the template parameter is an `unsigned int`, so `2` is implicitly converted to `2u`.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much - I didn't realise that it would be converted at all to a `Vector<2>`. Thanks! (I will accept this answer in 5 mins when it will let me ;) ).

Comment: Well that's the type that `operator*` is declared to return.

Answer (score 0):

Your `operator *` returns `Vector<2>`, not `Vector2`. The following will work:

```
Vector<2> a, b, c;
c = a * b;
```

Comment: Thanks - I have established that thanks to Oktalist, but I will go with the converting constructor as I think it's nicer to be able to write the Vector2 instead of having to rely on Vector<2> and loose the added functionality in the derived struct.